# join with a "not there" condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a linkage table `object_id -> property`:

```
id  |  prop
----|-------
1   |  ham
1   |  baz
1   |  whatever

2   |  spam
2   |  ham
2   |  whatever

3   |  ham
3   |  quux

4   |  foo
4   |  spam
```

How can I select only ids that have `ham` but not `spam` (in this example: `1` and `3`)? Do I have to resort to subqueries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM tbl o
 WHERE prop = 'ham'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null
                     FROM tbl i
                        WHERE o.id = i.id
                          AND i.prop = 'spam')
```

The same can be done using `LEFT JOIN`, but mysql query optimizer would produce similar execution plan for it. So it's a matter of preference on which to choose.

Bonus:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
  FROM tbl t1
  LEFT JOIN tbl t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                  AND t2.prop = 'spam'
 WHERE t1.prop = 'ham'
   AND t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Haha, I was just finishing a post about doing a JOIN but how subqueries are probably not that much worse in execution. You beat me to it though :)

Comment: I'm curious to see the JOIN version if possible.

Comment: i think in this case the `JOIN` is closer to what the query "means", since this is a foreign key.

Comment: @Eevee: "it depends". If I read the `NOT EXISTS` version I do it like "select all unique ids which have bar and not have spam". So it naturally fits the original task explanation. Whereas the `JOIN` based solution is a bit trickier to recognize

Answer (score 1):

```
Select id From table1 
Where prop = 'ham' and id not in (select id from table1 where prop = 'spam')
```